# How can i stop html5 audio from auto download

Tags: css, html, audio

I am using this

```
<audio src="audio.mp3" />
```

Now that file is big and system automatically downloads it when someone loads the page.

is there any way that when someone press play , only then system downlaods. Because that player is in my every page and it wastes the BW

Answer (score 12):

You can use the `preload='none'` attribute. [Documentation here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/media-elements.html#attr-media-preload)

The `"none"` attribute:

> Hints to the user agent that either the author does not expect the user to need the media resource, or that the server wants to minimise unnecessary traffic. This state does not provide a hint regarding how aggressively to actually download the media resource if buffering starts anyway (e.g. once the user hits "play").

Your HTML could look something like this:

```
<audio preload="none">
  <source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
  Your browser does not support this audio type.
</audio>
```